# Access violation when reading 2d array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, access-violation

My code seems to have a bug somewhere but I just can't catch it.  I'm passing a 2d array to three sequential functions.  First function populates it, second function modifies the values to 1's and 0's, the third function counts the 1's and 0's.  I can access the array easily inside the first two functions, but I get an access violation at the first iteration of the third one.

**Main**

```
text_image_data = new int*[img_height];
for (i = 0; i < img_height; i++) {
    text_image_data[i] = new int[img_width];
}

cav_length = new int[numb_of_files];
// Start processing - load each image and find max cavity length
for (proc = 0; proc < numb_of_files; proc++)
{
    readImage(filles[proc], text_image_data, img_height, img_width);
    threshold = makeBinary(text_image_data, img_height, img_width);
    cav_length[proc] = measureCavity(bullet[0], img_width, bullet[1], img_height, text_image_data);
}
```

**Functions**

```
int makeBinary(int** img, int height, int width)
{
    int threshold = 0;
    unsigned long int sum = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < width; k++)
    {
        sum = sum + img[1][k] + img[2][k] + img[3][k] + img[4][k] + img[5][k];
    }
    threshold = sum / (width * 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            img[i][j] = img[i][j] > threshold ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }
    return threshold;
}


// Count pixels - find length of cavity here
int measureCavity(int &x, int& width, int &y, int &height, int **img)
{
    double mean = 1.;
    int maxcount = 0;
    int pxcount = 0;
    int i = x - 1;
    int j;
    int pxsum = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < height - 2; j++)
    {
        while (mean > 0.0)
        {
            for (int ii = i; ii > i - 4; ii--)
            {
                pxsum = pxsum + img[ii][j] + img[ii][j + 1];
            }
            mean = pxsum / 4.;
            pxcount += 2;
            i += 2;
            pxsum = 0;
        }
        maxcount = std::max(maxcount, pxcount);
        pxcount = 0;
        j++;
    }

    return maxcount;
}
```

I keep getting an access violation in the ***measureCavity()*** function.  I'm passing and accessing the array ***text_image_data*** the same way as in ***makeBinary()*** and ***readImage()***, and it works just fine for those functions.  The size is [550][70], I'm getting the error when trying to access [327][0].

Is there a better, more reliable way to pass this array between the functions?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in your debugger? What did that tell you? Also, you may want to look into `std::array` and `std::vector`, and read up on smart pointers. Ohh, btw; range based for loops are also a nice modern thing.

Comment: Why are you using hard coded indices `1-5` in `sum = sum + img[1][k] + img[2][k] + img[3][k] + img[4][k] + img[5][k];`?? Unless height is greater than 5, that would be a problem. If it is greater than 5, `sum` will be incorrect.

Comment: In `makeBinary`, the second dimension is bounded by "width", but in `measureCavity` it's bounded by "height". I suspect a rows/columns confusion somewhere causing some bad indexing.

Comment: In your 2D array, the first index is "height" and the second index is "width". However, in your `measureCavity` function you are suddenly basing the range of the *second* index `j` on `height`. Why? This can easily lead to out-of-bounds problems. Are you sure that `height - 2` is always within `width`?

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Stepping through the code gives this error at the first iteration of the pxsum line: **Exception thrown at 0x00C58612 in SuperCavPixelCount.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.** <br> it should at least be able to access that initial index if the array still exists in the same location right?

Comment: @RSahu:  That part is taking the sum of the 1st 5 rows of pixels.  It just seemed shorter than adding an extra loop for each column.  Height is always much greater than 5.

Comment: Aaaaahh I see the error.  Thanks AnT, molbdnilo.  I switched the row/column indices.

Comment: For images, you may want to allocate a bitmap or a single array for the entire size of the image.  If you have a 1024 x 1024 image, then allocate a 1 dimensional array of 1024*1024 integers.  You can calculate the array offset using `index = row * (column_size) + column;`